# Migrate a single SVN tag to Git

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I am trying to migrate a specific tag from SVN to Git.

I have cloned the tag to my local.

```
git svn clone --authors-file=authors.txt svn://path/tags/1.0.0 1.0.0
```

Ran fetch to sync with remote repo

```
git fetch
```

Now, I would like to push the tag to remote git which should create a tag in Git. I have executed the below command for this.

```
git push origin --tags
```

It says "Everything up-to-date". However, it has **not** added any tag to Git.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is no tag added. You cloned that tag to be the master of a new repository named 1.0.0. If you want that result as Git tag pushed you first have to tag it with 1.0.0.

But besides that, `git-svn` is **not** the right tool for one-time conversions of repositories or repository parts. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are pleny tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

You can easily configure the tool with its rules file to make exactly what you want, even if it is to only convert one tag properly to Git. You can even split one SVN repo into multiple Git repos with one run easily or combine multiple SVN repos from one SVN root into one Git repo, or into multiple Git repos.

Comment: There's nothing wrong using git-svn for one time conversions - even the Pro Git book recommends it: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git#Subversion

Comment: @1615903 I don't care much about what a book tells, if experience tells a completely different story. Well, `git-svn` is easier to start with, but it produces much worse results, the history is rebuilt better by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), the tags are real tags and not branches in Git, if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually, with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git ...

Comment: ... repository easily. Yet another reason, with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal fetch will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper `svn2git` tags are where they belong. The conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn` ... There are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior.

Comment: ...and all that is fine, but just blatantly stating that it is not the right tool without any reasoning seems odd, especially when the Pro Git book - which is often referred to in many discussions about git - recommends it.

Comment: Now you have some reasoning and there is probably even more. Maybe it was written before `svn2git` existet, or the writers of the book just decided to write about the easier to use solution even if it produces worse results.

Comment: Thanks! The tag issue is resolved. However, I don't see any history. Using this approach the small repo has been migrated successfully. However, the same approach is not working for large repo. So, I have decided to move tag by tag. Now, I am stuck on history issue. I have looked at svn2git. It requires some softwares (libsvn, Qt etc.) and need to write rule book. It is going to be lot of work with respecting to learning and other things. Any workaround in git-svn itself?

Comment: Using `svn2git` is definitely worth it. Regarding the history of the tag, I don't know. I guess it is because you only converted the tag folder in SVN and the history is not in the tag folder but in some branch or trunk. You probably would have to do a full conversion of the repository to get the history for the tag. If you need help with the rules, just open another SO question and I'll be happy to help.